# Whether SWIPER by idangero.us is compatible with android versions 2.2.1 and 2.3.5.?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, swipe, swipeview

I have implemented SWIPE VIEW using the **plugin by idangero.us** from [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper).

I have implemented it it is working for the higher versions of android.

But, for the lower versions. I am neither able to see the slide nor able to swipe.

When I try swiping in the area of where the slide should be visible. I get the following warning,

```
W/webview(1133): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

I have implemented the swipe view dynamically.

To check if anything is visible in that swipe view, I had just added a slide statically in the HTML code.

**RESULT:**

I am able to see the slide.On swiping the slide,The slide moves left and right, and I do get the above mentioned warning.